# How to Store the result of classic sql query in a object which hasn't a entity table in database with hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I know how to store the result of an sql query in a object which has a representation in a table of the database (the object contains @Entity, @Id...) with `.addEntity()` method. But I want to store the result of a query in a object which hasn't a table in database.

Example:

Two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
            idUser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            pwd VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            nick VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            name VARCHAR,
            surname VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE comment (
            idComment INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            idUser INTEGER REFERENCES user,
            date TIMESTAMP,
            text VARCHAR
);
```

The following query:

`SELECT idComment, text,comment.idUser, nick FROM user,comment WHERE user.idUser=comment.idUser AND idUser=1;`

And the followin java class:

```
public class Comment{
  private int idComment;
  private String text;
  private User user;
}

public class User{
  private int idUser;
  private String nick;
}
```

How I can execute it with Hibernate and store the result in a Comment object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this work fine, but I "cheat" and do a false mapping:

The classes:

```
@Entity
public class Comment{
  private int idComment;
  private String text;
  @Embedded
  private User user;
}
```

`public class User{
      private int idUser;
      private String nick;
    }`

The query:

`List<Comment> comments = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT idComment, text,comment.idUser, nick FROM user,comment WHERE user.idUser=comment.idUser AND idUser=1;").addEntity(ProxyHistoria.class).list()`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a SQL query in Hibernate and get the result as an object type! take a look to this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

I hope this can help you!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I tried it before and i had a `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` caused by `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name user was not found in this ResultSet.`

Comment: That's strange... I'm doing this all the time... If you do the second example (that is what mahesh bellow is also telling to do) this will not look into the entity definition but instead will execute and return an object!!

Comment: Yes the second example, get a List<Object> but i want a List<Comment>, and if I trie to do like this: `List result = query.list();` and then `Comment c= result.get(0);´ teh cast failed and throw me a exception.

Comment: You should get the List<Object> and then convert to List<Comment> or you could try to map with dozer (for example: http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/domain_object_value_object_data_transfer_object_mapping_hibernate_lazy_load )

Answer (score 0):

You can get List data as below and assign to you `User` class.And you can't use like addEntity(), Because you don't have mapping for those classes,so they are not entity calsses. which means hibernate not aware of your `User or Comment` classes.So when ever we want to polpulate data to java class which are not mapped using hibernate.You can do as given below

```
List<Object[]> yourList = session.createSQLQuery("your sql query").list();
Iterator<Object[]> it = tyList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
Comment c=new Comment();
User u=new User();
String columnOne=null;
String columnTwo=null;
Object[] row = it.next();
if(row[0]!=null){
columnOne=row[0].toString();
}
if(row[1]!=null){
columnTwo=row[1].toString();
}
//Here set values corresponding to comment object
//Then you can set values related to user
//you can add the user object to list here
}
```

Comment: I dont know what I must do with this. Must I iterate and instantiate new Comment and User objects?

Comment: Yes, Create instance inside loop,then assign  values.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it automatically? like with the method ´.addEntity()´

Comment: No,you can't do automatically if the classes are not mapped.